# Python - change string chars into a list unless recurring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print all the characters in a string as a list but for each character to be printed once even if recurring. So far I have:

```
symbolsx = []
for line in ''.join(word_lines):
   for i in line:
       symbolsx.append(i)
```

This prints every character, even if the character is repeated.

Comment: Where are you printing the characters?

Comment: does keeping the order matter?

Answer (score 1):

`symbolsx = list(set(symbolsx))`

First pass the list to `set` function to remove duplicates, then reverted that set back to list by passing it to `list` function.

Comment: You should though put it back in a list for the OP

Comment: and also please add some explanation

Comment: The ordering of a set can't be guaranteed, whereas the ordering of a list can.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
symbolsx = []
for line in ''.join(word_lines):
    for i in line:
        if i not in symbolsx:
            symbolsx.append(i)
```